# Simple Kinematics (v-t graph)

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

A particle moves in a straight line. Its velocity–time graph is shown.

a. After 165 seconds the particle returns to the starting point. Find the value of T.

b. At what time does the particle have maximum speed?

c. Draw the displacement–time graph for this particle.

[image: v-t graph]

I'm struggling with A - how do I use the given information to work out the value T?

TIA.

Comment: Question a. seems to be incomplete.

Comment: @garondal this is interesting because this is copied and pasted from the textbook and the textbook has an answer for the question. See a complete screenshot of the textbook page:

https://imgur.com/a/sh2SQ6A 

EDIT: a number was missing from (a) in the original post :facepalm:, have now corrected it.

Comment: What is $x$ meant to represent?

Comment: So be a bit more careful while writing down the question. 

The integral from 0 to 165 should be zero. This yields T=45.

Comment: Sorry @user170231 that was edited in a rush, it was meant to be T rather than x.

Comment: Thanks @garondal  but there must be a way to do this without integrals right? This is part of my mechanics course and we haven’t done integrals yet.

Comment: Yes. The area of the trinangle below the $t$-axis needs to be equal to the rectangle and the triangle above the $t$-axis. This will give you an equation with $T=45$ as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area below the $t$-axis is $\frac{1}{2} 8 \cdot (165-75)=360$ m.

The area above the $t$-axis is $6T+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 6\cdot (75-T)$ m.

We need $360=6T+3(75-T)$ and we get the correct solution $T=45$ s.